# How to subclass generics properly?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have searched other questions/answers, an I'm still confused about this JAVA ISSUE.

If I want to subclass a type that takes generic parameters, how would I do so while using generic parameters for the subclass too without it getting shadowed?

For example:

```
public class A <T> extends ArrayList<T> {}
```

So if i instantiate my custom class, with say, Integers as the parameter, does it take that value as parameter for `<T>` for the ArrayList part of it too? If not, then how would I specify the type for the ArrayList?

And I know sub classing containers may not be the best idea in many situations, but in this case I have decided it would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes that would be how one goes about it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B<Integer> b = new B<Integer>();
    b.a = 1;
    b.b = "one";

    b.add(1);
    b.add(2);
}

public static class A<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    public T a;
}

public static class B<T> extends A<T> {
    public T b;
}
```

if you like you could even have them have different types, as long as you supply the super-class with it's type as well:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B<Integer, String> b = new B<Integer, String>();
    b.a = 1;
    b.b = "one";

    b.add(1);
    b.add(2);
}

public static class A<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    public T a;
}

public static class B<U, T> extends A<U> {
    public T b;
}
```

Comment: Okay I'm still unclear on that. So in the diamond brackets, is the U being passed to the A super class as the type? And are those place holders treated like variables, so the U is always the same and the T is always the same, etc? And if I used different types, do I have to have two generic types for the subclass in order to pass along the type for the super class?

Comment: a) Yes, the `U` is being passed to the superclass. And yes the `U` is only a generic parameter in the `B` class in order to pass it on to `A` b) The placeholders are treated as placeholders, so yes they are constant. c) You must have two generic types if you would like the user of the class to input the types, you could do `class B<T> extends A<Integer>` and hard-code `A`'s type and have `B` be the only class with a generic member.